# Best practice for reading data from Kafka to AWS Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, aws-lambda, amazon-redshift

What is the best practice for moving data from a Kafka cluster to a Redshift table?
We have continuous data arriving on Kafka and I want to write it to tables in Redshift (it doesn't have to be in real time).

- Should I use Lambda function?
- Should I write a Redshift connector (consumer) that will run on a dedicated EC2 instance? (downside is that I need to handle redundancy)
- Is there some AWS pipeline service for that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Kafka Connect is commonly used for streaming data from Kafka to (and from) data stores. It does useful things like automagically managing scaleout, fail over, schemas, serialisation, and so on.

[This blog](https://blog.insightdatascience.com/from-postgresql-to-redshift-with-kafka-connect-111c44954a6a) shows how to use the open-source JDBC Kafka Connect connector to stream to Redshift. There is also a [community Redshift connector](https://github.com/lepfhty/kafka-connect-redshift), but I've not tried this.

[This blog](https://engineeringblog.yelp.com/2016/10/redshift-connector.html) shows another approach, not using Kafka Connect.

*Disclaimer: I work for Confluent, who created the JDBC connector.*

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Does it mean I need a dedicated server(s) to run the Kafka Connect?

Comment: technically you can run it on the same node as your brokers, but that's generally a bad idea. There's a [reference architecture](https://www.confluent.io/whitepaper/confluent-enterprise-reference-architecture/) that might help .

Comment: @RobinMoffatt would you recommend this approach over sinking to S3 (with the S3 Connector) and ingesting the avro files from Redshift?

Comment: @JavierHolguera I don't know. Two factors I would investigate to determine this would be (a) do you need the files in S3 for other purposes? If so could be better option (b) performance of loading directly from JDBC vs landing to S3 and then ingest to Redshift