# Insert data into RedShift by using java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, amazon-redshift, apache-kafka-connect

I am a beginner here. I read data from kafka topic using kafka consumer. and that data is in console of the ide or on the local computer.
Now i have to push that data into redshift.

How to do that.
Is there any documentation that i can follow.

Comment: That is very broad. There should be numerous resources on how to use redshift.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon Redshift is an SQL database.

You can connect to it via JDBC from within the same VPC, or you can use the [Data API for Amazon Redshift](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/09/announcing-data-api-for-amazon-redshift/) to call an API from anywhere on the Internet.

You can then run normal SQL commands like `INSERT` and `SELECT`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have data in Kafka and want to put it somewhere else the most common and idiomatic way is to use Apache Kafka's Connect API. Kafka Connect is a plugin-based framework with which you can use the appropriate connector for your target technology. Learn more about Kafka Connect [here](https://rmoff.dev/kafka-connect-zero-to-hero) (or  [60 second overview](https://rmoff.dev/what-is-kafka-connect))

There is a [Redshift sink connector](https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connect-aws-redshift/current/index.html) for Kafka Connect that you can run yourself, or [hosted](https://docs.confluent.io/cloud/current/connectors/cc-amazon-redshift-sink.html) if you're using Confluent Cloud.

*See also [Best practice for reading data from Kafka to AWS Redshift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51595109/best-practice-for-reading-data-from-kafka-to-aws-redshift.)*